# Upgrading to Angular 6, importing and injecting HttpClient into a service has an unknown value

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-httpclient

[image: Here is the error that is being thrown in the console]

Here is the service's imports and the constructor

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, finalize, share, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

/* Internal Imports */
import { Config } from '../index';
import { Country } from '../models/country';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from '../helpers/index';

@Injectable()
export class CountryService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService,
        private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService) { }
```

Here is the imports and from the NgModule

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /* Angular Modules */
    CommonModule, RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule]
```

I followed the pattern for importing the module, client and injecting it into the service found in the Angular docs.

I have also tried the following in the service's constructor:

```
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService,
        private errorHandlerService: ErrorHandlerService) { }
```

which throws the same error.

The HttpClientModule is ONLY being imported into this NgModule.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "generic-app-name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "this is so I can post on Stack Overflow",
  "scripts": {
    "build.dev": "gulp build.dev --color --env-config dev",
    "build.dev.watch": "gulp build.dev.watch --color",
    "build.e2e": "gulp build.e2e --color",
    "build.prod": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.exp": "gulp build.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.rollup.aot": "gulp build.prod.rollup.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.prod.aot": "gulp build.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "build.test": "gulp build.test --color",
    "build.env1": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config env1 --build-type prod",
    "build.env2": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config env2 --build-type prod",
    "build.env3": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config env3 --build-type prod",
    "build.env4": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config env4 --build-type prod",
    "build.dev1": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config dev1 --build-type prod",
    "build.dev2": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config dev2 --build-type prod",
    "build.dev3": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config dev3 --build-type prod",
    "build.dev4": "gulp build.prod --color --env-config dev4 --build-type prod",
    "test.watch": "gulp test.watch --color",
    "generate.manifest": "gulp generate.manifest --color",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "e2e.live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "gulp": "gulp",
    "i18n": "ng-xi18n && gulp clean.i18n",
    "lint": "gulp tslint",
    "karma": "karma",
    "karma.start": "karma start",
    "postinstall": "gulp check.versions && gulp build.bundle.rxjs && npm prune && gulp webdriver && gulp print.banner",
    "reinstall": "npm cache clean && npm install",
    "serve.coverage": "gulp serve.coverage --color",
    "serve.dev": "gulp serve.dev --color --env-config dev",
    "serve.e2e": "gulp serve.e2e --color",
    "serve.prod": "gulp serve.prod --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.aot": "gulp serve.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.exp": "gulp serve.prod.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "serve.prod.rollup.aot": "gulp serve.prod.rollup.aot --color --env-config prod --build-type prod",
    "start": "gulp serve.dev --color",
    "start.deving": "gulp start.deving --color",
    "tasks.list": "gulp --tasks-simple --color",
    "test": "gulp test --color",
    "e2e.ci": "gulp build.prod --color && gulp build.js.e2e --color && gulp e2e --color",
    "tests.all": "npm test && npm run e2e.ci",
    "webdriver-start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver-update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "compodoc": "node_modules/.bin/compodoc -p src/client/tsconfig.json",
    "serve.compodoc": "node_modules/.bin/compodoc -s"
  },
  "author": "Minko Gechev <mgechev>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/ansi-colors": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/async": "^2.0.32",
    "@types/browser-sync": "^0.0.34",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.39",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.33",
    "@types/express-serve-static-core": "4.0.49",
    "@types/fancy-log": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/gulp": "^3.8.36",
    "@types/gulp-filter": "^3.0.29",
    "@types/gulp-load-plugins": "^0.0.28",
    "@types/gulp-protractor": "^1.0.29",
    "@types/gulp-sass": "^0.0.29",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.109",
    "@types/node": "^10.3.2",
    "@types/rimraf": "0.0.28",
    "@types/run-sequence": "0.0.28",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "^2.53.39",
    "@types/systemjs": "^0.19.31",
    "@types/yargs": "^6.5.0",
    "@types/zone.js": "^0.0.27",
    "async": "^2.1.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.17.3",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "compodoc": "0.0.41",
    "connect-history-api-fallback": "^1.3.0",
    "cssnano": "^3.7.7",
    "deep-extend": "^0.6.0",
    "event-stream": "^3.3.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-history-api-fallback": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-concat-css": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-inline-ng2-template": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-noop": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "~1.1.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-progeny": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "^0.5.4",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-template": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "7.0.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^3.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.10",
    "is-ci": "^1.0.9",
    "isstream": "^0.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^3.0.0",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "merge-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "remap-istanbul": "^0.8.4",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "rollup": "^0.41.4",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^7.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "^2.2.1",
    "semver": "^5.3.0",
    "serve-static": "^1.11.1",
    "slash": "~1.0.0",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.2",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.34",
    "tildify": "^1.2.0",
    "traceur": "^0.0.111",
    "ts-node": "^6.1.0",
    "tslint": "^5.10.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "vinyl-fs": "^3.0.3",
    "walk": "^2.3.9",
    "yargs": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "^0.6.4",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^6.0.4",
    "@types/es6-shim": "^0.31.37",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.15",
    "@types/through2": "^2.0.33",
    "angular-2-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.8.0",
    "angular2-draggable": "^1.2.1",
    "ansi-colors": "^2.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "graceful-fs": "^4.1.11",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "mailcomposer": "^4.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.15.1",
    "ng2-slim-loading-bar": "2.0.4",
    "ng2-slimscroll": "1.2.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^11.1.1",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^0.4.1",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^8.8.0",
    "nodemailer": "^4.6.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "socks": "^2.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.41",
    "through2": "^2.0.3",
    "tsickle": "^0.29.0",
    "uws": "^10.148.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your package.json file? 
Also, besides that HttpClientModule in that specific module, do you have the regular HttpModule somewhere else?

Comment: @monogate HttpModule was deprecated? I do not have it referenced anywhere. I will add my package.json to the original question

Comment: Paste the authService and errorHandlerService, I want to see if they depend on HttpClient as well. If they depend on it specify the module in which they are provided. I am thinking that they are causing trouble to you.

Comment: auth.service does rely on HttpClient, errorHandler does not. They are both within the same module as CountryService.